# How do I validate URNs?

Tags: java

What's the easiest way to validate that a string is a valid [URN](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2141.txt)?

**Edit** Using URI is not a correct solution! URIs are allowed to have all kinds of things that URNs can't, like `&`

Comment: If you want to validate string with Uniform Resource Names (URNs) 8141: [rfc8141][1]  You can refer to [URN8141Test.java][2] and [URN8141.java][3]

It has been used in our team for a few years.  


  [1]: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8141
  [2]: https://github.com/BruceZu/broken_colored_glass/blob/master/project/src/test/java/URN8141Test.java
  [3]: https://github.com/BruceZu/broken_colored_glass/blob/master/project/src/main/java/URN8141.java

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you only need to validate it, you can use a regular expression. The following will match only RFC2141 compliant URNs:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class UrnTest {
    public static final Pattern URN_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
        "^urn:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,31}:([a-z0-9()+,\\-.:=@;$_!*']|%[0-9a-f]{2})++$",
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for(String urn : args) {
            boolean isUrn = URN_PATTERN.matcher(urn).matches();
            System.out.println(urn+"  :  "+(isUrn ? "valid" : "not valid"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this. Of course, this only checks if a string is a possible URN, not that it actually complies to some registered URN namespace. For this you would need a URN namespace database.

Comment: The regular expression is not compliant to [RFC2141](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2141.txt). For example, namespace allows upper case characters, while your regex doesn't.

Comment: A good point! I have amended it to do case insensitive matching.

Comment: I would prefer a standard library? any one? java.net.URI doesn´t seem to be able to validate or get parts or the URN

Comment: Is there a way to make this regex safe against overflowing the stack? As it is, SonarQube complains of it with the "Regular expressions should not overflow the stack" error https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/regex/RSPEC-5998

Comment: Simply replace the `+` with a `++`. In this case, SonarQube is complaining about something that cannot happen. The left-hand side of the alternation cannot match a `%` and the right hand side can only match a `%`. This means the algorithm will never back-track as only one branch can ever be possible. This is too subtle for SonarQube to reason out, but we can make it obvious by using the possessive quantifier `++` to explicitly disallow backtracking (which we won't be doing anyway)

Answer (score 3):

I recently released [urnlib](https://github.com/slub/urnlib). It implements a class for representing an Uniform Resource Name (URN). It also implements parsing and serialization according to the constraints defined in [RFC 2141](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2141).

It's released on Maven Central and aims to serve as a network identifier handling library just like the native Java URL and URI classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [jcabi-urn](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-urn/index.html) and its class [`com.jcabi.urn.URN`](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-urn/apidocs-0.7.16/com/jcabi/urn/URN.html)

Comment: Short note (like can be found in jcabi java-doc v.0.8): "NOTICE: the implementation is not fully compliant with RFC 2141. It will become compliant in one of our future versions. Once it becomes fully compliant this notice will be removed."